# tawdis error in sitefinity 6.0 script error

Tags: validation

i use a sitefinity 6.0, i use tawdis.net for validate all, i only validate the home page, i read that always sitefinity render this script, but i need erase or hide of tawdis, but i dont find this line in any file of sitefinity, i dont know where appear this script in sitefinity, any idea?  but always appear this line i dont know how to fix this.

```
> 139. //<![CDATA[
> 140. Sys.Application.setServerId("ctl02", "ctl00$ctl02");
> 141. Sys.Application._enableHistoryInScriptManager();
> 142. //]]>
> 143. X</script>
```

thanks, the x is an error in tawdis.

Comment: do you use a custom master page in your site? maybe you are doing something there? 
Can you post a link to the public site?

Comment: i use tawdis.net to validate this http://fogafin.gov.co/

Comment: when you view the source of the Home page - there is definitely no X before the closing script tag.